# Secure Connection between two mobile (Android and/or iOS) devices

Tags: encryption, network, certificates, certificate-authority, python

I've a **`Device A`** which will communicate with multiple devices on a network (BLE and/or NFC).

All the devices will be handled a **Token** upon authentication which somehow needs to be transferred over to the **`Device A`** over network securely and confidentially.

What is the best possible way to achieve it.? I guess something like SSL handshaking will be secure, but a simpler solution will be preferred.

Basically **`Device A`** needs to act as a server.

### Research done so far has led me to the following flow:

- **`Device A`** manages to send a **public key** to client.
- The client uses the key to encrypt the **Token** and send it to **`Device A`**.
- Only **`Device A`** can read the **Token** and authenticate the client.

### Problems with this approach (and their solutions, as per my limited knowledge while dealing with security systems):

- The token is same and the public key might repeat as well, giving a weak point in the system.

  - *The token will be transferred over the network with a **nonce**.*
- **MIM attack**: Any **`Device X`** can mimic **`Device A`** and send a public key to client and initiate transaction. Now **`Device X`** knows the **Token** and mimic the client.

  - ***The `Device A` should possess some kind of digital certificate to prove its authenticity. The digital certificate will be assigned by a server written in Python/Django. And the all the clients should be able to verify the certificate without interacting with server.***

## Concerns:

- Since I need this for mobile devices, I need the public private key pair to be as short as possible but yet secure.

## Questions:

- How can I implement the last part algorithm? Is there any open source python library available for generating, issuing and verifying certificates?
- Is the algorithm secure ? I'm a newbie in security and would like any valuable feedback.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You don't care if the public key repeats. It's meant to be public. If you buy a 2-year SSL cert, your site will use the same public key for 2-years. Not a problem.

Comment: What do you mean that the token may repeat? When a client authenticates it may get the same token for different sessions? That sounds like a vulnerability.

Comment: @NeilSmithline the token will repeat. It appeared to be a vulnerability to me as well. So I introduced a Nonce as well. It should overcome the vulnerability. Right? I'm not sure about it, please provide your feedback considering it. Thanks

Comment: The repeating token sounds problematic and a nonce sounds like a good fix. That said, without a better understanding of the whole setup, that's about the best that I can say. Hope that helps.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Yes, I understand. Surely it helped :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a very cool project.  It seems that you have rediscovered the very problem that [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) was designed to solve.

Looking at your example, why would you not just use PKI both ways? Or can you not control the certificates at both ends?  You could look at SSL session initialization to see how you could transfer a confidential message under the gaze of a warden.

If you are rolling your own solution, you will find that secure key storage is a very difficult problem to overcome.

EDIT:
To address your well thought out concern, Elliptic Curve Cryptography is often used on mobile devices because of [computational limitations](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ecc-case-mobile-encryption/).

Comment: Yeah. Don't roll your own. SSL already solves the MiTM attack problem so you don't need to.

Comment: I would agree to not use your own secure channel.  But, I would recommend re-implementation for educational purposes, sometimes it can be the best way for the deepest understanding.  But, I would certainly recommend against using it in any production capacity.

Comment: @M15K Thanks a ton. I'll read about it and bother you guys in case I have any doubts.

Comment: @NeilSmithline SSL already solves MiTM attack, but the problem is (or I'm not yet aware of it) that I need to secure the connection between two MOBILE (Android and/or iOS, I forgot to mention) devices. How can I implement SSL for mobile clients is really what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @M15K I also forgot to mention my concerns. Please have a look at it whenever possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is a well thought out concern.  Elliptic Curve Cryptography is often used on mobile devices because of [computational limitations](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ecc-case-mobile-encryption/).

Comment: @M15K Please include this in your answer. It seems like what I've been looking for. As per your suggestion, I did implement PKI and Digital Signature, but the key pair consumes too much data. Thanks a lot.